# OnAppearing() method is performing before calling the OnCurrentPageChanged() method

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, display, tabbedpage

For the first time I'm restricting the `onAppearing()` methods in all child pages of tabbed page. I need to call the `onAppearing()` when I change the tab. For that, I'm using `OnCurrentPageChanged()` to call the `onAppearing()` method.
When I change the tab, I'm calling the `OnCurrentPageChanged()` and giving them access to run the `onAppearing()` functionality. `onAppearing()` is calling before calling the `OnCurrentPageChanged()`.

**TabbedPage code:**

```
public partial class VendorScheduleTabbedPage : Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage
    {
       public int isCount;
        public VendorScheduleTabbedPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["dayOnAppear"] = false;
            Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["weekOnAppear"] = false;
            Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["monthOnAppear"] = false;
            On<Android>().SetBarItemColor(value: Color.FromHex("#6699FF"));
            On<Android>().SetBarSelectedItemColor(value: Color.Orange);
        }
        override protected void OnCurrentPageChanged()
        {
            isCount = 1;
            if (this.CurrentPage.Title == "Week")
            {
                Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["weekOnAppear"] = true;

            }
            if (this.CurrentPage.Title == "Month")
            {
                Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["monthOnAppear"] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["dayOnAppear"] = true;
            }
            base.OnCurrentPageChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**Week Page code(child page):**

```
public WeekSchedulePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            timeSlot = new List<VendorScheduleTimeSlot>();
            scheduleSlots = new List<VendorScheduleTimeSlot>();
            lstVendorsData = new List<ScheduledCustomersVM>();
            SortedList = new List<ScheduledCustomersVM>();
            scheduledCustomersList = new List<ScheduledCustomersVM>();
            rescheduledCustomersList = new List<RescheduledCustomersVM>();
            ConfirmBtn.IsVisible = true;
            ConfirmBtn.IsEnabled = false;

            vendorDayAndHoursDataVM = new VendorDayAndHoursDataVM();
            lstDaysAndHours = new List<VendorDayAndHoursDataVM>();
            lstQuestionsData = new List<VendorQuestionsDataVM>();
            overlay.IsVisible = false;
            Alert.IsVisible = false;

            presentWeekDay.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");

            currentDayName = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
            currentDate = DateTime.Parse(presentWeekDay.Text);

        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            var isAppear = Convert.ToBoolean(Application.Current.Properties["weekOnAppear"].ToString());
            if (isAppear == true)
            {
                ConfirmBtn.IsVisible = true;
                ConfirmBtn.IsEnabled = false;

                overlay.IsVisible = false;
                Alert.IsVisible = false;

                Application.Current.Properties["dayOnAppear"] = true;
                Application.Current.Properties["monthOnAppear"] = true;
                ConfirmBtn.IsEnabled = false;
                scheduledCustomersList.Clear();
                rescheduledCustomersList.Clear();

                presentWeekDay.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");

                currentDayName = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();

                weekwiseTimeslotClick();

                base.OnAppearing();
            }

        }
```

Here I need to call `OnCurrentPageChanged()` method first instead of the `OnApearing()` method. And `OnCurrentPageChanged()` will give the `bool` value to perform the code which is in `OnApearing()` method.

Comment: Why not give the bool to the init of the second page from the first page action?
Why do you need to pass it via the Page.Methods?

Comment: It's a tabbed page...By defaultly i'm displaying some alerts in 3 tabbed pages.those all alerts are displaying at a time in current child page of a tabbed page.for that i restricted my onAppearing() methods in all child pages...Now I'm unable to change the bool values to the session to perform onAppearing() methods when click on particular tab.

Comment: Are you seeing this issue only on Android, or for both? If only on android, it’s probably because the android platform loads the next tab automatically, in order to display the tab quickly when it’s tapped

Comment: Why not create a method in the week (or other) page that you can call from the `OnCurrentPageChanged()` method? Just make sure the page is not null, and if not call that method to to the things you need to do to the page. If the page is null, you can instantiate it and then call the method. However if OnCurrentPageChanged is called after the page appears, then it should not be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, `onAppearing` is called before `OnCurrentPageChanged` while in iOS `OnCurrentPageChanged` is called before `onAppearing`.

1.As `jgoldberger` suggested, you can call method in each Page after `CurrentPageChanged`:

```
    override protected void OnCurrentPageChanged()
    {
        if (this.CurrentPage.Title == "Week")
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["weekOnAppear"] = true;

            NavigationPage naviPage = this.Children[0] as NavigationPage;
            WeekPage page = naviPage.RootPage as WeekPage;
            page.test();

        }else if (this.CurrentPage.Title == "Month")
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["monthOnAppear"] = true;

            NavigationPage naviPage = this.Children[1] as NavigationPage;
            MonthPage page = naviPage.RootPage as MonthPage;
            page.test();
        }
        else
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["dayOnAppear"] = true;

            NavigationPage naviPage = this.Children[2] as NavigationPage;
            DayPage page = naviPage.RootPage as DayPage;
            page.test();
        }

        base.OnCurrentPageChanged();
    }
}
```

2.You can use [messaging-center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to notify specific page to perform some actions after `CurrentPageChanged`:

```
    override protected void OnCurrentPageChanged()
    {
        string testStr;

        if (this.CurrentPage.Title == "Week")
        {
            testStr = "Week";
        }else if (this.CurrentPage.Title == "Month")
        {
            testStr = "Month";
        }
        else
        {
            testStr = "Day";
        }

        MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(new object(), "CurrentPageChanged", testStr);

        base.OnCurrentPageChanged();
    }
```

And in each page:

```
public partial class MonthPage : ContentPage
{
    public MonthPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, string>(new object(), "CurrentPageChanged", async (sender, arg) =>
        {
            if (arg == "Month")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arg);
                //do something
            }
        });
    }

    public void test() {

        Console.WriteLine("test");
        //do something
    }
}
```

BTW, you should use `if...else if...else` instead of `if...if...else` in your control statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still facing this issue on our migration of **Xamarin** forms from 4.0 to **5.0**. Due to the existing code, it is not easy to go with the solution posted here and I found a better solution is to set a flag with the current page index in your tabbed page by overriding **OnPropertyChanged** event and looking for CurrentPage property.

```html
protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
{
    if (propertyName == nameof(CurrentPage))
    {
        myCurrentTabVariable = Children.IndexOf(CurrentPage);
    }
    base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
}
```

**myCurrentTabVariable** is a flag that you could access from any of your tabbed page. You could design that by having as a property in your base tab page or as simple as a global variable.

This ensures that before the OnAppearing method of your tab page is called, the flag is set and check for this flag in other tab's OnAppearing method to stop executing if the current tab is not the same.